# Temperature for wild-yeast fermented cider

Tags: fermentation, cider, fermentation-temperature, wild-yeast

I just bought 10 gallons of freshly pressed unpasteurized apple sweet cider.

I am breaking it into two batches, planning to ferment one of them with french wine yeast and the second one will be naturally fermented. It will be my first time doing the fermentation naturally... What's the appropriate fermentation temperature for natural yeasts?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natural yeasts like natural temps :p

I would recommend ale fermentation temps, somewhere between 16 C and 20 C. You can go higher, but that will give you higher alcohols. Going colder will probably make the yeast go to sleep.

Comment: Sounds right. I split 10 gallons into 3 batches, with 2 naturally fermented. After 2 days of fermentation, I noticed that one batch works fine with 16C-18C, and the second one works only if I get it to 20C.